# How do I get a max record for each week in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to get a query that returns the info for the largest order, week by week.

My very basic concept is something like this:

```
select 
    datepart(ww, order_date), order_id, order_revenue, order_margin 
from 
    orders
where 
    order_date >= 1/1/2016
    and order_id in (select max order for each week)
```

Basically I just want the week #, order id, order revenue, and order margin for the largest order margin record for each week.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a "Windowing Function"
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/window-functions-in-sql-server/

```
select * 
from 
( select datepart(ww, order_date), order_date, order_id, order_revenue, order_margin 
       , row_number() over (partition by datepart(ww, order_date) order by order_margin desc) as rn 
   from orders 
  where order_date >= 1/1/2016 
) tt 
where tt.rn = 1 
order by order_date desc
```

And I think you need to single quote the date

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly different method; it has a lot more details, but that's because I designed it to run in AdventureWorks (don't know how to tell which version) so I could test the functionality.

```
USE AdventureWorks

;WITH OrderDetails
    AS (
        SELECT soh.SalesOrderID, CAST(soh.OrderDate AS DATE) AS OrderDate,
            SUM(sod.OrderQty * (sod.UnitPrice - pch.StandardCost)) AS OrderMargin
            FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
                LEFT JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
                    ON soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
                LEFT JOIN Production.ProductCostHistory pch
                    ON sod.ProductID = pch.ProductID
            WHERE soh.OrderDate >= pch.StartDate AND soh.OrderDate <= pch.EndDate
            GROUP BY soh.SalesOrderID, soh.OrderDate
        ),

MaxOrder
    AS (
        SELECT DATEPART(yy,OrderDate) AS Year, DATEPART(ww,OrderDate) AS Week,
            MAX(OrderMargin) AS MaxOrderMargin
            FROM OrderDetails
            GROUP BY DATEPART(yy,OrderDate), DATEPART(ww,OrderDate)
        )

SELECT mo.Year, mo.Week, od.SalesOrderID, '$'+FORMAT(mo.MaxOrderMargin,'#,0.00') AS OrderMargin
    FROM MaxOrder mo
        INNER JOIN OrderDetails od
            ON mo.MaxOrderMargin = od.OrderMargin
        WHERE DATEPART(yy,od.OrderDate) = mo.Year AND DATEPART(ww,od.OrderDate) = mo.Week
    ORDER BY Year, Week
```

This has slightly improved functionality over the previous example in one regard only, and that is because it will include ALL the orders with that margin, even if there are multiple. I would note, however, that this can be achieved using RANK() instead of ROW_NUMBER(). Show here using a CTE:

```
USE AdventureWorks

;WITH OrderDetails
    AS (
        SELECT soh.SalesOrderID, CAST(soh.OrderDate AS DATE) AS OrderDate,
            SUM(sod.OrderQty * (sod.UnitPrice - pch.StandardCost)) AS OrderMargin
            FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
                LEFT JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
                    ON soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
                LEFT JOIN Production.ProductCostHistory pch
                    ON sod.ProductID = pch.ProductID
            WHERE soh.OrderDate >= pch.StartDate AND soh.OrderDate <= pch.EndDate
            GROUP BY soh.SalesOrderID, soh.OrderDate
        ),

OrderRank
    AS (
        SELECT DATEPART(yy,OrderDate) AS Year, DATEPART(ww,OrderDate) AS Week,
            SalesOrderID, '$'+FORMAT(OrderMargin,'#,0.00') AS OrderMargin,
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(yy,OrderDate), DATEPART(ww,OrderDate) ORDER BY OrderMargin DESC) AS MRank
            FROM OrderDetails
        ),

MRank
    AS (
        SELECT Year, Week, SalesOrderID, OrderMargin
            FROM OrderRank
                WHERE MRank = 1
        )

SELECT * FROM MRank
```